# Binding posted values to view model using default binder - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, model-binding

Can the Model Binder in MVC bind posted values to a view-model object containing hierarchy?

I have a Customer, Order and OrderItem tables.  OrderItem.OrderID points to Order.ID;  and Order.CustomerID points to Customer.ID i.e. the common Customer -> Order -> OrderItem setup.

And I have a view model – Customer which contains Order objects and then OrderItem objects as well.

I have created the EF model objects using the designer tools in VS. (created database tables first in SQL, then created the classes automatically using the EF tools)

On a single page (view), let's say, I will allow the user to create a new Customer record, an Order, and some OrderItem(s).

When the user fills the form (creates a new Customer, Order and OrderItems on this one view), clicks on the submit button; will the default binder move all the values from the posted values to my view model? (the view model class carries properties for Customer, Order, OrderItem in a hierarchy i.e. Order is a property within Customer and OrderItem is a property within Order).  Is EF smart enough to map posted values to such an object?

Comment: That's a lot of questions - you should probably consider splitting these up.  Also, rather than try and research your specific questions, you might be better running through creating some example applications  - have a look at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx for an example

Comment: I realize it looks like 6 questions, but as I mentioned earlier it really is only one concept.  Also, I have seen the link you mention before - where does it answer the basic question - how to save hierarchical objects?  I do not see it addressed.  And that is my problem.  The examples on MVC/EF are too basic.  StanK - Do you know the answer, and even if you think they are 6 separate questions - do you know the answer to any one of them?  It would be nice to know how you would do it.  Thanks.

Comment: StanK, you are right, my questions were confusing, even to me, when I read them again!  I have edited and shortened the text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MVC is smart enough to handle this binding.  It is fairly common in MVC to build up a 'complex' View Model made of several properties which are themselves Models.   Binding to collections and dictionaries is harder, but entirely possible.

In EF, you can easily define relationships between objects (e.g. there is a 1 to many relationship between Customer and Order), and EF will handle this just fine.  The code for the 'Create customer with order and order items' will (I imagine) be fairly straightforward but I'm not an EF expert, though - so I will have to leave detailed answers to someone else.

However, the EF code for an 'Edit Customer and/or Order and/or Items' screen would actually be quite complicated - and so you'd probably be better splitting these off into separate actions, as this would simplify the code quite a lot.